# python global operator emulation

Tags: python

in Lutz's book I read how to emulate global operator in a function body.
I created p.py file in documents folder:

```
var = 0
def func():
    import p #import itself
    p.var = 15
func()
print(var)
```

output:

```
15
0
```

I thought is is supposed to simply print 15, but by some reason it also added 0 to output. So I'm wandering why has it happened.

for example, when i do the same thing in terminal, but in the **main** module, it works as I want:

```
var = 0
def func():
    import __main__ #import itself
    __main__.var = 15
func()
print(var)
```

and output is

```
15
```

I have python 3.7.7

Comment: Question is, why for god's sake would you employ such dirty hacks for a keyword not very "clean" in the first place?

Comment: @matszwecja Honestly, making assignments into the parent scope more explicit by using the form `scope.var = value` is definitely superior to pulling names into the current scope with the `global` (or `nonlocal`) keyword. *These keywords* are the “dirty hack”. That said, creating the scope reference via `import` is itself a hack, that much is true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Disagree there, keywords are bad but this is much worse. Seems like someone who doesn't understand why the global keyword is bad in the first place and wants to avoid the keyword without avoiding it's actual problems

Comment: @matszwecja I'm learning python now so i test everything i read to understand it better.

Comment: and why is it a hack?

Comment: @IceCube It's a hack because you are trying to emulate `global` behaviour without actually using `global`.

Comment: @matszwecja oh ok, but I just read that it's possible, but stuck in this question while testing the feature, I mean hack

Comment: @mousetail I dunno, I'm a fairly seasoned developer (both in Python and generally). I'm confident that I *do* understand the ins and outs of scoping, and the Python scoping rules, and in particular those silly keywords, are pretty bad by comparison with other systems.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Standard importing is of course perfectly fine. But a module importing itself **is** a dirty hack mimicking behaviour of `global`.

Comment: @matszwecja Yes, the last sentence in my initial comment is explicitly agreeing with that. What I'm saying is that `global` *itself* is *also* a hack (though admittedly sanctified by being in the language), and at least OP's hack has a tangible advantage (which my initial comment explains) over the other hack.

Comment: I wouldn't call a built-in language feature a hack. It is not a good practice to use it usually, but it is there by design. I also do not see any advantage of self-import compared to explicit `global` over a specific variable.

Comment: @matszwecja It's a language design hack. Call it a misfeature if you prefer. Either way, it's bad -- and not just because you shouldn't use global variables (`nonlocal` has the same issue as `global`). The advantage of OP's hack, as explained in my initial comment, is that individual assignments to non-local variables make their non-lexical scoping more explicit, because each assignment mentions the target scope. I'm not saying this should be used, just that it has this one advantage over `global`.

Comment: Other languages that have closures also don't require (or even allow) explicit scope definition. Usually scope is defined by the location of the declaration. The only reason `global` and `nonlocal` keywords are needed in python is because variables are not declared so it's ambiguous whether you want to access a existing or create a new variable.

Comment: @mousetail “Other languages that have closures” do lots of different things, and those that do it well *do* allow/require explicit scope qualification — either, as you say, via explicit declarations, or by explicitly specifying the target scope.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Name any language that allows explicit scope qualifications. Not saying they don't exist but I've never used/header of any

Comment: @mousetail C++, R, Java. Just off the top of my head.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm true, I guess there is benefit and precedence for such a feature,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are not modules: files are used to *define* modules. If you run `p.py` as a script that contains `import p`, there are two modules, `__main__` and `p`, both created from the same file, but each with its own global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's break this into few steps.

- First of all:

self-importing of a module is not a good thing to do - one example why is because of the things you noticed in your question.

```
import p #
var = 0
def func():
    p.var = 15
func()
print(var)
print(p.var)
```

Running this, you will notice that `var` and `p.var` are actually 2 separate variables, even though logically they are the same thing, just in a different namespace.
You've also got `func` and `p.func`, which again do the same but are 2 separate things.

- Second problem:

Global keyword should be used only when *absolutely necessary*. When you have a global variable, it is much harder to track when it changes and control the flow of your program - [Global Variables Are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) (not everything applies to Python, but most points still stand).

- Finally, why you are actually seeing the behaviour you see:

In Python when the module is imported, all of it is executed just like the main script you are running.
Let's say you have `pr.py` file containing only this:

```
print("text")
```

Importing such a module with `import pr` would be enough to see `text` on console, because it gets executed on import.
That's why you see 15 printed (in `import p`, `print(var)` happens - and because we are in module `p`, `p.var` and `var` are the same *here*). Then `import p` finishes and we get to `print(var)` - but because we are now in `__main__` module, `var` is not the same as `p.var`, and it still has the original value of `0`.

Why does `import __main__` work different? It's because it is handled specially by Python, as can be read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#import-main). In short, `__main__` is initialised from the start of the program, so `import __main__` does not cause the code to run again, just like importing some module more only causes it to be executed once.

Comment: well. firstly, why are `var` and `p.var` in different namespaces(importing itself creates identifical namespace, but somewhere else in memory?)?
Secondly, when I run this code without `print(var)`, there is no output

Comment: As you can read in @chepner answer, you've got 2 namespaces after `import p` - `__main__` containing `var` and `p` containing `p.var`. And yes, they represent separate objects in memory.

Comment: in the first block i run my code in p.py file so why doesn't `p.var = 15` in `func()` doesn't change it?

Comment: or do I not understand how do programs run in python?

Comment: Because at the beggining you are in `__main__` module, not `p` module. That's the name that Python specifically assigns to the module you start your program with.

Comment: so if I run program in IDE, it'll send me in `__main__`?

Comment: Yes, all the definitions in the initial (entrypoint) script are considered to be in the `__main__` module.